Loading external javascript file in index.html of React App
I have this React app in which I load my external javascript file inside the  tag as below
index.html:
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/assets/externalJavascript.js"></script>
</head>

Inside externalJavascript.js, I have this below:
let queryParams = window.location.search.substring(1);

console.log("Query: ", queryParams)

window.loadFunc = function() {
            console.log("Script Loaded!");
          };

I access this loadFunc() inside my desired component using window.loadFunc()
All this is not working but if I make the js file inline in the index.html, it's working! Like this below:
<script>
      (function () {
          let queryParams = window.location.search.substring(1);

          console.log("Query: ", queryParams);

          window.loadFunc = function loadFunc() {
            console.log("Script Loaded!");
          };
      })()
    </script>

When my app loads, I get the query in console log and also I can access the loadFunc() only when it is inline script.
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you!

instead of "type=text/javascript" try type="module"

Consider providing more clarification as to why this should work.
